# Excel table filter achieving something like an IN statement in SQL language

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm convinced this has to be something very straightforward - I just couldn't find any stack exchange posts referencing it. I apologize if it's already out there.

I'm trying to filter out a couple of numbers from a long list that I have in an excel table. Something similar to an 'in' clause in SQL, but I'm not using a formula - just trying to use the table functionality in Excel 2010. Any help appreciated on how to input multiple numbers/id's at once.

The closest I've found so far is using advanced filters as suggested here - but it's not quite as simple as keying something into the search bar: 
https://superuser.com/questions/623380/excel-filter-a-column-by-more-than-two-values

Thanks

[image: Excel dropdown filter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, not really.  Within Excel, you can filter with two conditions (via an `or`), but to my knowledge you can't do more than two.

If you are interested in a hack, here is one.

1. Create a second table with a list of values you want to filter.  Make sure it's a table, not a range, for scalability
2. Create a new field in your original table, and vlookup your value against the new table.  Something like this:

.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@UID],NewTable[[#All],[FilterItems]],1,FALSE)),"","Y")
```

Now your original table will have a field you can filter on "Y" to get items in your list.

And because you made it a table, not a range, if you add items, the vlookup will dynamically scale to include those new items, without you having to do the cursed A:A range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Home Tab > Highlight Column of values > Sort & Filter button > Filter > and from the excel sheet you can filter it by number from the top of the column of values.

Comment: Because it's in a table, the Filter button is not an option.

Comment: can you copy the values into another sheet?

Comment: yea, but I'm sure there is a way to enter this into the drop down  :/ Thanks for trying, though